# Converting pgSQL to Doctrine

Tags: postgresql, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I am receiving the error **[Syntax Error] line 0, col 257: Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got '18'** when this Doctrine Query Builder query executes.  The database is pgSQL.

```
        $query = $this->entityManager
            ->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('s.subscriptionReference')
            ->from(
                'OTDatabase\Entity\Membership\Member',
                'm'
            )
            ->innerJoin(
                'OTDatabase\Entity\Membership\MemberSubscriptions',
                's',
                'WITH',
                'm.record = s.memberReference'
            );

        $query
            ->andWhere('s.list = 1');

        $query
            ->andWhere('m.validated IN (:validated)')
            ->setParameter('validated', array('1', '3'));

        $query
            ->andWhere($query->expr()->lt(gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s') , 's.subscription_begins'));

        $query
            ->andWhere('
            (
                ( now() <= s.subscriptionExpires )
                OR
                ( s.subscriptionBegins <= now() AND s.subscriptionExpires IS NULL )
            )');

        $result = $query->getQuery()
                        ->getArrayResult();
```

For future reference the **correct query** (with the help of @Logan Bailey) is:

```
        $query = $this->entityManager
            ->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('s.subscriptionReference')
            ->from(
                'OTDatabase\Entity\Membership\Member',
                'm'
            )
            ->innerJoin(
                'OTDatabase\Entity\Membership\MemberSubscriptions',
                's',
                'WITH',
                'm.record = s.memberReference'
            );

        $query
            ->andWhere('s.list = 1');

        $query
            ->andWhere('m.validated IN (:validated)')
            ->setParameter('validated', array('1', '3'));

        $query
            ->andWhere($query->expr()->lt('s.subscriptionBegins' , ':subscriptionDate'))
            ->setParameter('subscriptionDate', gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

        $query
            ->andWhere($query->expr()->orX(
                $query->expr()->lt(':subscriptionDate' , 's.subscriptionExpires'),
                $query->expr()->isNull('s.subscriptionExpires')
            ));
```

Comment: What is the generated SQL, you should be able to get this from $query->getQuery()->getSQL()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wrap the date in quotes. You should probably be using it as a bound parameter.

```
$query
   ->andWhere($query->expr()->lt(':subscriptionDate' , 's.subscription_begins'))
   ->setParameter('subscriptionDate', gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```